# Access Functions via Dictionary

Tags: python, list, function, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a function like this:

```
def abc(a,b):
    return a+b
```

And I want to assign it to a dictionary like this:

```
functions = {'abc': abc(a,b)}
```

The trouble is, when assigning it to the dictionary, since the arguments are not yet defined, I get the error:

```
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

I would do the obvious thing and define the arguments ahead of time but I need to define them in a loop (and then call the function based on locating it in a list) like this:

```
functions_to_call = ['abc']
for f in functions_to_call:
    a=3
    b=4
#This is supposed to locate and run the function from the dictionary if it is in the list of functions.
    if f in functions:
       functions[f]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I need to define them in a loop (and then call the function based on locating it in a list)

Then what's the issue with simply saving the function object in the dictionary:

```
functions = {'abc':abc}
```

and *then* applying `a` and `b` to the function while looping:

```
functions_to_call = ['abc']
for f in functions_to_call:
    a, b = 3, 4
    if f in functions:
       functions[f](a, b)
```

Comment: Thanks! As a follow-up, what if I had functions that accepted different arguments? I know I couldn't just use functions[f](a,b) if one took (c,d). Is there a simple way to make the arguments conditional in the loop?

Comment: Follow-up question posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39926423/access-functions-in-dictionary-part-2

Answer (score 3):

You assign a reference to the function **without** any arguments, and then supply them when calling it:

```
functions = {'abc':abc} # Assignment: no arguments!
functions_to_call = ['abc']
for f in functions_to_call:
    a=3
    b=4
    if f in functions:
            functions[f](a, b) # calling with arguments
```