# Access Functions in Dictionary Part 2

Tags: python, list, function, python-3.x, dictionary

As a follow-up to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39926137/access-functions-via-dictionary):
I have 2 functions that look like this:

```
def abc(a,b):
    return a+b

def cde(c,d):
    return c+d
```

And I want to assign it to a dictionary like this:

```
functions = {'abc': abc(a,b), 'cde': cde(c,d)}
```

I could do this, but it would break at 'cde':

```
functions = {'abc':abc, 'cde':cde}

functions_to_call = ['abc', 'cde']
for f in functions_to_call:
    a, b = 3, 4
    c, d = 1, 2
    if f in functions:
       functions[f](a, b)
```

Also, what if cde took 3 arguments?

Comment: Use python-generic along with python-specific tag, it will give your question more traction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a seperate sequence of `args` and use the splat operator (`*`):

```
>>> def ab(a,b):
...   return a + b
... 
>>> def cde(c,d,e):
...   return c + d + e
... 
>>> funcs = {'ab':ab, 'cde':cde}
>>> to_call = ['ab','cde']
>>> args = [(1,2),(3,4,5)]
>>> for fs, arg in zip(to_call,args):
...   print(funcs[fs](*arg))
... 
3
12
```